# Correct tooltip for deleting own question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete, tooltips

Hovering the `Delete` of my own question, I get

[image: tooltip of deleting own question]

And when I click on it, it allows me to delete my question immediately.

Can this tooltip be fixed to say "delete this post" for the OP?

Comment: technically is a "vote to delete".  It is just the OP has a binding vote (when the post is eligible for deletion)

Answer (score 4):

No, this would be quite meaningless. As far as I know, even diamond moderators see this same tooltip.

There is indeed a delete vote being cast - it might be binding, or it might need more votes to  have effect.

The check whether to actually delete the post or not is performed **after** the vote is cast.

If you apply this logic, then you will also have to change the tooltip for 20k users who can delete posts, when there are already 2 other delete votes, since the third will actually cause the post to be deleted, and this becomes just too complicated/time consuming to be worth the effort, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, OP is the moderator of its own profile as well as its own post either question or answer.

So OP can perform an action without anyone's review and can delete the post without any others vote.

OP can delete his/her question/answer immediately and that's why this tooltip shows "**vote to delete this post**". And OP's vote is enough to delete his/her own post.

Hope this answer will be able clear your doubts.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  But could we just simply remove 8 characters to make it easier to understand (and avoid future meta posts which are duplicates of this one)?  Definitely.